# Pass by reference to const in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Is there a c++ pass-by-reference-to-const Delpi equivalent in XE2? The c++ code would be:

```
void passByRef(const MyClass& param);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void passByRef(const MyClass& param);
```

The `const` here says that you cannot modify the value to which the reference refers.

Assuming that `MyClass` is mapped to a Delphi class there is nothing equivalent. In Delphi a class is a reference type. You can pass a const reference like this:

```
procedure Foo(const param: TMyClass);
```

This means that the function is not allowed to modify the value of `param`.

```
param := ...; // this would result in a compilation error
```

But the method is allowed to mutate the object to which `param` refers.

```
param.DataMember := ...; // compiles
param.SomeProperty := ...; // compiles
param.MutateObject(); // compiles
```

Delphi is simply missing this aspect of `const` that is available in C++.

If you instead mapped to a record rather than a class, things would be a little different. Then you'd have:

```
procedure Foo(const param: TRecord);
```

Again you could not assign to `param`, but because this is a value type, you are also prevented from directly modifying any data members of `param`.

```
param.DataMember := ...; // does not compile, for TRecord being a record
```

But the compiler won't stop you calling methods on such a record that mutate the internal state. This is something of an oversight in my view, but hard for the language designers to avoid given the tools at their disposal. Again, the design of C++ is simply richer in this area, with more fine-grained constness specification allowed.

For this reason I would strongly recommend that you consider not writing record types with instance methods that mutate the record's state.

Comment: It is worth to mention that Delphi already supports passing const as reference by using [ref] decorator: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Constant_Parameters

Comment: @George that was added after this answer was written